# How to mask a UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, calayer, uibezierpath

I have a complicated Stack view that has many arranged labels and buttons. When I have attempted to mask the whole stack view in order to enforce a corner radius, the buttons within the stack view no longer worked (**action selectors not triggered upon touch inside**). I have decided to simplify the problem first to one button and one mask like so:

```
    let mask = UIView()
    mask.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    mask.backgroundColor = .green
    mask.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    view.addSubview(mask)
    mask.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    mask.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    mask.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    mask.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    
    
    
    btn = UIButton()
    btn.backgroundColor = .red
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    btn.setTitle("More info", for: .normal)
    btn.tintColor = .black
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreInfoTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    
    view.addSubview(btn)
    btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    
    
    view.layoutSubviews()
    view.setNeedsLayout()
    
    btn.mask = mask
```

This masks the button correctly but unfortunately the mask is placed in front of the button and thus taps on the button are **never registered.**

This is the view hierarchy:

[image: Mask overlaying button]

Am I missing something?

Comment: i dont know what you want to achieve sir ... but one workaround is to turn off user Interaction to mask view .. other option is dont add mask view to your view ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you are masking for achieving round corners if you guide me i can suggest you better solution .. but for your current case if you turn off user interaction of mask view .. your button will start responding

```
mask.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: perhaps I spoke to soon, please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907180/how-to-mask-a-uistackview-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the button example you specified above, as I don't know what you want to do with the stackview.

You'll style the `mask` as you want with the corner radius. And then you'll add the `button` to the mask but with a transparent background and make it fill the parent i.e. `mask`

```
let maskView = UIView()
view.addSubview(maskView)
maskView.setCornerRadius() // implement this
maskView.setupConstraints() // implement this

let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = .clear
maskView.addSubview(button)
button.fillParent() // implement this
```

The same logic will apply for the stackview. You just need to style the container view or mask view.

Alternatively, you can include both the button and mask view in a container view:

- the mask beneath the button
- the button to be clear
- the container view to be clear
- style the mask view
- have both mask and button fill the container view (or size them as would work best for you