# How to mask a UIStackView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I understand that UIStackViews are not rendered the same way the rest of view components are and thus they cannot be masked. Nonetheless I am sure there are work arounds.

**Is there any way to mask a UIStackView? Specifically a stack view that has other UIStackViews as subviews.**

Comment: perhaps you can mask all of the subviews individually (provided that they are not stack views). However, I am not sure if you can create one mask and reuse it for all subviews

Comment: Depending on what your goal is, You could create a container view (Uiview) for the stack view. And then you could add background colors, borders, etc to that.

Comment: @valosip I am not masking the stack view to add colors, borders. etc. I am masking the stack view for other reasons such as animation.

Comment: What animation are you trying to add to it or it’s sub view stackviews?

Comment: When the user taps a button, a menu slides out from underneath it and vice versa. This animation would be childsplay if I could get masks to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, I believe. Although it's a subclass of `UIView`, you still can't even set a `backgroundColor` to it. Apple says:

> The UIStackView is a nonrendering subclass of UIView; that is, it does not provide any user interface of its own. Instead, it just manages the position and size of its arranged views. As a result, some properties (like backgroundColor) have no effect on the stack view. Similarly, you cannot override layerClass, draw(*:), or draw(*:in:).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview